# Obj-C - NSPredicate filter key containing space in its title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a key (field) in my database that contains a space in its name (don't get me started, lol...). I'm trying to use NSPredicate to filter the values in this key. How can I write the following string to account for the space in the key title 'off leash'?

```
self.restSubFilter = [self.neighbourhoodData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(off leash contains[c] %@)", @"YES"]];
```

Comment: Can you substitute the key with `%K` as explained in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html ?

Comment: you can also use single quotes and make use of %K as @jtbandes points out.  Should look something like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[c] '%@'",@"off leash",@"YES"]` But beware %K is for keypaths, you may still end up with `@"'%@' CONTAINS[c] '%@'",@"off leash",@"YES"`